# How to map integer to string value in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dictionary, integer, transformation

I have this python dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
        '1':'A',
        '2':'B',
        '3':'C',
        '4':'D',
        '5':'E',
        '6':'F',
        '7':'G',
        '8':'H',
        '8':'I',
        '9':'J',
        '0':'L'
        }
```

The I have created this simple pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
ds = {'col1' : [12345,67890], 'col2' : [12364,78910]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
print(df)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    col1   col2
0  12345  12364
1  67890  78910
```

I would like to transform each and every digit in `col1` (which is an `int` field)  to the correspondent letter as per dictionary indicated above. So, basically I'd like the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
    col1   col2 col1_transformed
0  12345  12364            ABCDE
1  67890  78910            FGHIJ
```

Is there a quick, pythonic way to do so by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution (notice that `8` is repeated in your dictionary -- a typo? -- and, therefore, my result does not match yours):

```
def f(x):
    return ''.join([dictionary[y] for y in str(x)])

df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(f)
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2   col3
0  12345  12364  ABCDE
1  67890  78910  FGIJL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df[df.columns + "_transformed"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [
        "".join(dictionary.get(ch, "") for ch in s) for s in map(str, x)
    ],
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    col1   col2 col1_transformed col2_transformed
0  12345  12364            ABCDE            ABCFD
1  67890  78910            FGIJL            GIJAL
```